# How to filter data.frame based on date in R

Tags: r, filter, tidyverse, subset

```
library(tidyverse)
dat <- data.frame(id = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5),
                  class = c("A", "A", "B", "C", "C"),
                  value = c(12, 34, 24, 24, 11),
                  date = c(as.Date("02/27/92", "%m/%d/%y"), as.Date("02/27/99", "%m/%d/%y"),
                           as.Date("03/01/91", "%m/%d/%y"), as.Date("02/27/99", "%m/%d/%y"), as.Date("06/28/91", "%m/%d/%y")))

> dat
  id class value       date
1  1     A    12 1992-02-27
2  2     A    34 1999-02-27
3  3     B    24 1991-03-01
4  4     C    24 1999-02-27
5  5     C    11 1991-06-28
```

I would like to do the following:

- for `class = A`, keep the rows where `value > 10`
- for `class = C`, keep the rows where `value > 11`
- for each distinct `class`, keep the row with the largest (or more recent) `date`

Here's my attempt and error:

```
> dat %>% filter((class %in% "A" & value > 10) | (class %in% "C" & value > 11)) %>%
  group_by(class) %>% filter(max(date))
Error in `filter()`:
! Problem while computing `..1 = max(date)`.
x Input `..1` must be a logical vector, not a date.
ℹ The error occurred in group 1: class = "A".
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`filter(max(date)` should be `filter(date == max(date))`